# MySQL: view or create a new table?

Tags: mysql, view, create-table

I'm doing a java project in which I have to use a MySQL database with a big amount of data (geonames). Since I need to verify if a proper name is a geoentity I need only 3 coloums of a table. So I would like to know if it is better to use a view of this table or just create another table with only this three attributes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Creating a view always causes performance bottleneck and you should therefore avoid it until it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: So it's better to create a new table?!

Comment: Why do you want to create an additional (unnecessary) table? Just select the columns you need and use them as and when required.

Comment: Finally I used an index! And it takes 7 seconds for a query instead of 4 minutes! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need creating a view in the case. 
If you do this, maybe more overhead on this db.

BTW, creating proper index will affect a lot performance.

Comment: yes it is what I've done finally! Now instead of 4 minutes it takes 7 seconds! :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not just selecting the 3 columns like that:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from your_table
```

Comment: If in terms of time it's better to do in this way I will do it! :)

Comment: Normally you would not create a view if you don't need to select all columns of a table.

Comment: Finally I used an index! And it takes 7 seconds for a query instead of 4 minutes! :D